# Slow down Rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am adding forward force based on `GetAxis ("Vertical")` and a speed modifier up to `normal max speed`.

I am also allowing "speed boost" that adds more force on top of the normal added force up to `boosted max speed`.

what i am having hard time with is slowing the object down once boost period is over

So basically if you were booster to a faster speed then normal max speed and you cannot speed boost no more, slow the object back to normal max speed.

this is what i got so far:

```
    float velocity;
    float magnitude = myRigidBody.velocity.magnitude;
    float vertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
        boost = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
        boost = true;
    }
    if (!boost) {
        velocity = vertical * speed;
        Vector3 force = myRigidBody.transform.forward * velocity;
        if (magnitude + force.sqrMagnitude < normalMaxSpeed) { 
            myRigidBody.drag = 0f;
            myRigidBody.AddForce (force, ForceMode.Impulse);
        } else if (magnitude + force.sqrMagnitude >= maxTrust + 50) { 
            myRigidBody.drag = 1.5f;
        }
    } else if ( magnitude < boostedMaxSpeed) { 
        velocity = vertical * (speed + speedBoost);
        myRigidBody.AddForce (myRigidBody.transform.forward * velocity, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

This some what working but there must be a better solution other then changing drag.

Comment: This is C# not Unityscript. What type of object is this?

Comment: Its just a gameObject with Rigidbody

Comment: Sorry, I meant to askthe shape of the object....If this is just a rolling ball or just a character. The shape of the object matters since there are many ways to do this.

Comment: this is a capsule wrapped in a game object , the Rigidbody is on the game object not on the capsule. the game object has no collider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than changing the drag, there are still other ways to do this. You just have to experiment to see which one works best.

**1**.Change the drag

```
myRigidBody.drag = 20f;
```

**2**.Add force to the opposite velocity.

```
public Rigidbody myRigidBody;
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 oppositeVelocity = -myRigidBody.velocity;
    myRigidBody.AddRelativeForce(oppositeVelocity);
}
```

**3**.Decrement or Lerp the current velocity back to the normal force.

```
public Rigidbody myRigidBody;
Vector3 normalForce;

void Start()
{
    normalForce = new Vector3(50, 0, 0);

    //Add force  
    myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector3(500f, 0f, 0f);
    //OR
    //myRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(500f, 0f, 0f));
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Go back to normal force within 2 seconds
    slowDown(myRigidBody, normalForce, 2);
    Debug.Log(myRigidBody.velocity);
}

bool isMoving = false;

void slowDown(Rigidbody rgBody, Vector3 normalForce, float duration)
{
    if (!isMoving)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        StartCoroutine(_slowDown(rgBody, normalForce, duration));
    }
}

IEnumerator _slowDown(Rigidbody rgBody, Vector3 normalForce, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;
    //Get the current position of the object to be moved
    Vector3 currentForce = rgBody.velocity;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        rgBody.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(currentForce, normalForce, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }

    isMoving = false;
}
```

**4**.Change the *dynamic friction* of the [Physics Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html). You can't use this method because it requires collider which you don't have.

```
//Get the PhysicMaterial then change its dynamicFriction
PhysicMaterial pMat = myRigidBody.GetComponent<Collider>().material;
pMat.dynamicFriction = 10;
```

---

It's really up to you to *experiment* and decide which one works best for you. They are useful depending on what type of game you are making. For example, *#4* is mostly used when rolling a ball because it uses physics material which requires frequent collision to actually work.

The method used in *#3* gives you control over how long the transition should happen. If you need to control that then that's the choice.

Comment: I love this answer, very detailed and helpful. thanks very much. i tried to do negative force but for lake of knowledge it failed so thanks for teaching. however i ended up just playing with drag

Comment: You are welcome. Using the drag from your question is just enough. You should also try #3 which lerps the velocity.